# Pidgin conversation tabs style per user

Tags: windows-7, pidgin

Is there a way/plugin to customize the style of Pidgin conversation window tabs per conversation (per user)? I have looked at [How do I change the font Pidgin uses? The background color?](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#LookFeel) but that changes it globally for all conversations. What I am looking for is per tab based on username/protocol etc. This is on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I want to do this too, because when interacting with bots, e.g. the ZNC bot, the font needs to  be monospace for the ASCII tables that the bot sends to look OK.

On the other hand, proportional font for all other conversations is easier to read.

However, as far as I can tell there's [no way to do this with Pidgin](https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/15357), plus their font selection UI has been [a mess](https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/3061) since 2007, without any progress being made on that front.